# Scroll aleatorio

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Quisiera saber como hacer para que en el momento que carga el contenido del html, el scroll finalice en una posición aleatoria.

las funciones son estas

```
> function scrollWin(a,b) {
>             window.scrollTo(a,b);
>         }
> 
> 
>   function aleatorio(a,b) {
>          return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a));
>          }
```

y la llamo con

```
scrollWin (aleatorio (0,0),aleatorio (500,1000))
```

Pienso en alguna función con el scroll, para que al momento de cargar el html este aparezca aleatoriamente en cualquier posición del documento.

Comment: Nos podrías mostrar el código con que has intentado lograr esta funcionalidad?

Answer (score 3):

Esto para una posición muy especifica

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
```

O puedes utilizar la navegación interna del documento sirve para posicionarte

1. Ponemos un elemento con un id

   `<div id="myComponente">Hola</div>`
2. Por codigo o url vamos a la posicion

   `window.location = "#myComponente";` o `http://myurl/mypath#myComponente`

Espero que te sirva, Saludos!!

Comment: Si bien la respuesta puede ser correcta lo ideal sería esperar a que el OP diera más información sobre su problema.